# Is there any way to export the created configuration (nodes and data) to normal properties in zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am new to zookeeper. I have properties file with 1000 or more than 1000 properties.

Sample properties looks like below. I can able to create path and store values in zookeeper using apache curator API method. This process I call it as a Import.

```
debug=false 
trace=false 
logging.exception-conversion-word=%wEx 
logging.file.max-history=0
logging.file.max-size=10MB 
logging.pattern.dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 
logging.pattern.level=%5p 
logging.register-shutdown-hook=false 
spring.application.name=My App
```

I want to know whether is there any way to export those created configuration (nodes and data) or properties back to normal properties looks like above?

I want all the tree of data using that I will convert those data back to my original properties.

Comment: What do you mean by properties? Are you searching for a way to read a data from Zookeeper? Apache Curator library should be enough for everything.
Or to dump all the tree of the data? There are open source projects for it as well.

Comment: Hi @Valentina, I have updated my question for better understanding. I can able to get single data for any path. I want all the tree of data so that I will convert those data back to my original propeerties.